# Couldn't Redirecti page after form action submit to node server.(react front)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-router

I'm currently building a web with react, and in this app I'm also building a register functionality, since the user is mainly going to type Chinese in the input tag, I use a form action to submit the form instead of using onChange property in each input (as far as I know, React community haven't found a proper way to deal with the onChange bug when typing Chinese).

And the main problem is that since I'm using the form action to submit the form data, I couldn't get response from the server, and that cause me unable to authenticate and redirect the page.

I would like to know whether there is something wrong with my logic or how to solve this problem by code, thank you;.

I tried using "redirect" in the backend, it works partially, by partially I mean that I couldn't receive response in the front end because I used a form action to submit instead of fetch or axios, so that I don't know how to authenticate in this case.

Front End using React

```
<form action='http://localhost:8000/' method='post'>
.....</form>
```

Back End Using Node with Express

```
db.collection('memberProfiles').insertOne(userModel)
.then(response => {res.redirect('http://localhost:3000/memberProfile').send('token');})
                .catch(err => res.send('Page ERROR'));
client.close();
```

Comment: use `target="_self"` to see server response in the page itself

Comment: @පවිඳු adding target seems not working, what kind of action should I specified? thank you